# QML - Dial not appearing correctly in StackLayout for Fusion style

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, stacklayout

For context, I will be making my own QML Controls style (for which I will be using the included Fusion style as a starting point), and for this I am making a Controls gallery of sorts.

In this gallery I have multiple tabs which are used to select between Pages in a StackLayout.  Curiously, when I put a Dial in the second tab, I noticed that it wasn't displaying correctly at all.

[image: Tab 2 - Only part of dial wheel renders]

It is still able to turn though.

[image: Tab 2 - Turned dial]

When I place the Dial in the first tab, it does render correctly.

[image: Tab 1 - Dial displays correctly]

Curiously, for many styles (Material shown below) the dial does display correctly.

[image: Material tab 2 - Dial displays correctly]

The following is the QML code used:

```
Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent 
        spacing: 0
        
        TabBar {
           id: tabBar
           Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.fillWidth: true 
           Layout.minimumHeight: tab1.height
           Layout.maximumHeight: tab1.height
           
           TabButton {
               id: tab1
               text: "Tab1"
               width: implicitWidth
           }
           TabButton {
               text: "Tab2"
               width: implicitWidth
           }
        }

        StackLayout {
            currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
            Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.fillWidth: true 
            
            Page {
                anchors.fill: parent 
                Dial {
                    inputMode: "Circular"
                }
            }
            Page {
                anchors.fill: parent
                Dial {
                    inputMode: "Circular"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is causing this discrepancy and how can I fix it?

Comment: I can reproduce this. Looks like a but to me.

Comment: Yeah after a bit of digging I'm starting to think the same.  I wonder what the underlying cause is - The Fusion dial's background seems to be drawn rather than use primitive Components, so perhaps Canvas/something else isn't rendered correctly when in a StackLayout?  If so that is quite concerning and I'm surprised it hasn't been caught in another form.  Off to submit a bug report